# What is the difference between the following the git config

Tags: git, git-flow

**.git/config 1**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://johndoe@example.com//repositories/plugins/myproject.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

**.git/config 2**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://johndoe@example.com//repositories/plugins/myproject.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop]
```

However, on both repositories, when I typed `branch -a`, both return

```
git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 3):

If you try to pull from the develop branch of the repo that does not define `[branch "develop"]` using `git pull`, you will get an error complaining that you haven't specified a remote branch. Git will suggest that you run `git branch --set-upstream develop origin/develop` in order to create that entry and properly track the remote branch.

Comment: This is not correct. With `git/config 1`, no matter I have change in both `develop` and `master` branches, everything will be pushed to the remote when I use `git push`. I guess `git pull` will become a problem though.

Comment: Derp. Yes. I got it backwards. Edited.

Comment: @Yoga: If that is a problem, you may want to consider a more conservative setting for `push.default`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have branch `develop` tracking a branch on the remote repository in the first one.

To see the difference run `git branch -avv` on each repository.  This will show all branches (local and remote), what commit each is on and which remote branches (if any) are tracked by each local branch.

Comment: Yes, but I was able to push to the remote branch, just can't pull from it. I am wondering what setting affect this behaviour?